# Firebug finding things when searching in the html tab, but not in the script or net tabs

Tags: search, firebug

I'm trying to search for some text output somewhere random in the response. Searching in the html tab definitely finds the stuff I'm looking for, however searching in the script and net tabs yields nothing. This is very confusing to me, since the script and net tabs should be supersets of what is available in the html tab. Is my understanding not correct? I find it incredibly frustrating when searching the script tab seems so flaky and refuses to find things I know are there.

So note that I'm simply print_r'ing some object in PHP, and I know where it is showing up in the dom. Also, barring a bizarre tear-in-the-fabric-of-spacetime level javascript/php oddity, I'm 100% confident that the dom isn't being populated by some weird cryptic javascript.

Another note: I'm searching in a flash facebook app, so theres a bunch of nested iframes and complications going on. Not sure if this makes a difference (I would hope it wouldn't anyways).

So my basic question is: whats the difference between searching in the html, script, and net tabs?

Comment: Can you show an example? Is the searched value actually there?

Comment: I already mentioned I could find the searched text by searching in the html tab. Its definitely there.

Comment: So, can you show an example? Perhaps it's a bug in Firebug, perhaps something else going on.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an example I can give right now. Maybe I'll put one up if no one has a clear idea of how searching in those tabs are different from eachother.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is very confusing to me, since the
>   script and net tabs should be
>   supersets of what is available in the
>   html tab. Is my understanding not
>   correct?

Well, your first understanding was incorrect, but your suspicion that it was incorrect was, in fact, correct. ;)

The search bar means different things when you're in each of those tabs. The search bar only searches the top-level objects in whatever pane you're in. So, when you're in the Net tab, the search bar is searching only the key info on fetched files. When you're on the Script tab, it's only searching within DOM elements and files that are (or might be) scripts.

Here, I'll use this page (yeah, literally [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438695/firebug-finding-things-when-searching-in-the-html-tab-but-not-in-the-script-or-n)) to demonstrate.

1. Start the Firebug window and reload the page.
2. Switch to the Net tab and select All (next to Clear and Persist). In the search bar, start typing 
   `jquery.min.js` and you'll see it start highlighting the line `GET jquery.min.js` sourced from ajax.googleapis.com. Those top level lines are all that are being searched when you're on the Net tab. That's it's job; to help you find information about fetched files quickly, so anything else is extraneous.
3. Likewise with the Script tab. If you search for `function bQ`, you'll quickly find it in jquery.min.js, but it won't bother searching plain HTML content because you're on the Script tab.

Does that help?

Comment: Yes, that does help! However, on point 3, searching in the script tab does indeed find your "function bQ" text in the html. It also finds it in jquery.min.js . This example would still lead me to believe what I was seeing is weird

Comment: Hah, I knew I'd get myself in trouble doing that. I tried to be too cute: when I put it into the comment, then it *was* in the html (and now twice, since you mentioned it). If you like, manually review the JS, pick a snipped I didn't mention and search for it, and I think everything will be happy. Happy hacking!

Comment: Oop, now I see what you mean; the plain HTML from the URL is definitely in the script tab. I don't have a good answer on that one.